# Como fazer o ResponseEntity do Spring MVC retornar em uma nova pagina?

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, controller, thymeleaf

Tenho um método de um controller de relatório (postado abaixo), ao qual me retorna um PDF.

O problema é que retorna o pdf na mesma aba da aplicação e isso esta matando a mesma. Como posso fazer para retornar em uma nova aba ?

Método Post que é submetido no html.

```
@PostMapping("/vendasEmitidas")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> 
   gerarRelatorioVendasEmitidas(PeriodoRelatorio periodoRelatorio) 
   throws SQLException, JRException {

    byte[] relarotio = 
      relatorioService.gerarRelatorioVendasEmitidas(periodoRelatorio);

    return ResponseEntity
       .ok()
       .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
       .body(relarotio);

}
```

HTML que chama o relatório

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorate="~{layout/LayoutPadrao}">

<head>
    <title>Relatório - Vendas Emitidas</title>
</head>

<section layout:fragment="conteudo">

    <div class="page-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1>
                Relatório de vendas emitidas
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form method="POST" th:object="${periodoRelatorio}" th:action="@{/relatorios/vendasEmitidas}">
            <th:block th:include="fragments/MensagensErroValidacao"></th:block>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group  col-sm-12">
                    <label for="dataInicio">Data de criação</label>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control  aw-form-control-inline-sm  js-date" 
                            id="dataInicio" th:field="*{dataInicio}" autocomplete="off"/>
                        <label for="a" class="aw-form-label-between">a</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control  aw-form-control-inline-sm  js-date" 
                            id="dataFim" th:field="*{dataFim}" autocomplete="off"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary">Emitir</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>

</html>
```

Estou utilizando:

- Spring MVC 5.0.2
- SpringBoot 2
- Jasper
- Thymeleaf

Comment: Você não vai resolver isso no backend, vai ter que alterar o link onde chama o relatório

Comment: Alguma sugestão de como melhor faze-lo?

Comment: De forma genérica `<a href="url" target="_blank">Meu link</a>`

Comment: O meu problema é que não chamo por um link mas por um post em um formulário que me retorna um pdf através de um responseEntity
ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE).body(relarotio).

Comment: Posta a parte onde você chama

Comment: É o método postado acima. Ou estais se referindo ao HTML?

Comment: De qualquer forma coloquei também o HTML

Comment: O problema é que você manda via `form`, poderia utilizar ajax para isso, mandar as informações de forma assíncrona e depois que receber abrir uma nova janela

Comment: Atualmente estou no trabalho, quando chegar em casa a noite eu formulo uma resposta

Comment: Obrigado. Fico no aguardo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui que o relatório abrisse em outra aba, o seu código vai ficar assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{layout/LayoutPadrao}">

    <head>
        <title>Relatório - Vendas Emitidas</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var form = $('#form');
                form.submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var dados = form.serialize();
                    $.post({
                        url: form.attr('action'),
                        data: {
                            dados: dados
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                            var win = window.open();
                            win.document.write('<iframe src="' + fileURL + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>')
                        },
                        error: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            })
        </script>
    </head>

    <section layout:fragment="conteudo">

        <div class="page-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1>
                    Relatório de vendas emitidas
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form method="POST" th:object="${periodoRelatorio}" th:action="@{/relatorios/vendasEmitidas}" id="form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group  col-sm-12">
                        <label for="dataInicio">Data de criação</label>
                        <div class="form-inline">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control  aw-form-control-inline-sm  js-date"
                                   id="dataInicio" th:field="*{dataInicio}" autocomplete="off"/>
                            <label for="a" class="aw-form-label-between">a</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control  aw-form-control-inline-sm  js-date"
                                   id="dataFim" th:field="*{dataFim}" autocomplete="off"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary">Emitir</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</html>
```

A única coisa que mudei na estrutura do seu HTML foi o atributo de id, adicionei ele para poder manipular o formulário de maneira mais fácil no Javascript.

Adicionei o seguinte script no seu código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('#form'); //Pega o formulário pelo id
    form.submit(function (e) { // Executa a função ao clicar o botão submit do formulário
        e.preventDefault(); // Previne a página de dar submit e direcionar para o action do form
        var dados = form.serialize(); // Transforma os dados do formulário para que sejam passados via ajax
        $.post({ //Faz uma requisição ajax com o método POST
            url: form.attr('action'), // Define a url a ser acessada
            data: {
                dados: dados //Dados a serem enviados
            },
            success: function (data) { // Função que será executa em caso de sucesso
                var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                var win = window.open();
                win.document.write('<iframe src="' + fileURL + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>')
            },
            error: function(data) { // Função a ser executada em caso de falha
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

A parte importante no código é essa:

`function (data) {`

> Data é a informação recebida na requisição

`var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });`

> Um Blob object representa um objeto, do tipo arquivo, com  dados
>   brutos imutáveis. Blobs representam dados que não estão
>   necessariamente em um formato JavaScript nativo. A interface [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/File) é
>   baseada no Blob, herdando  funcionalidade blob e expandindo-o para
>   suportar arquivos do sistema do usuário.

`var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);`

> Cria um novo objeto URL, cujo tempo de vida está ligado ao document na
>   janela na qual este objeto foi criado. O novo objeto URL representa o
>   objeto File ou o objeto Blob passado como argumento.

`var win = window.open();`

> O método open() da interface [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) carrega o recurso especificado no
>   contexto de navegação (janela, `<iframe>` ou aba) com o nome
>   especificado. Se o nome não existe, uma nova janela é aberta e o
>   recurso especificado é carregado em seu contexto de navegação.

`win.document.write()`

> Escreve dentro de um [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document)

A última linha da função é uma forma de contornar um [problema com o Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45700813/5325043):

```
'<iframe src="' + fileURL + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>'
```

> Especifica um `iframe` tendo como conteúdo o arquivo que foi recebido do servidor, sem bordas e com altura/largura definidos em 100%

Comment: Valeu - Obrigado, vou testar.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode colocar a seguinte tag no form target="_blank"